# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $n\times n$ Toeplitz matrices using induction.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a $n\times n$ Toeplitz matrices.

$\begin{bmatrix} 
a & c &0 &0&...&0&0 \\ 
b & a &c &0&...&0&0 \\
0 & b &a&c&...&0&0 \\
\vdots & \vdots  &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0  &0&0 &\dots&b&a
\end{bmatrix}$

(Hint:- Eigenvalues is of the form:- $\lambda_k=a+2\sqrt{bc}\cos(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}), k=1,2,3,..,n)$

My attempt:-
I tried to apply induction on $n$.

For $n=1$. The result is true.
Assume result true for $n=m$.

For the matrix $(n-1)\times(n-1)$

I made the block matrices.
$\begin{bmatrix} 
a & c &0 &0&...&0&\vdots&0 \\ 
b & a &c &0&...&0&\vdots&0 \\
0 & b &a&c&...&0&\vdots&0 \\
\vdots & \vdots  &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots &\vdots& \vdots\\
\dots & \dots  &\dots &\dots &\dots&\dots &\vdots& \dots\\
0 & 0  &0&0 &\dots& b &\vdots& &a
\end{bmatrix}$

I am not able to proceed further. Could you give some help?

Comment: $\cos(k\pi/(n+1))$, $k=1,2,...,n$ are the roots of [Chebyshev's polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Roots_and_extrema). The case $c=0$ is clear. Assume $c\neq0$. Subtract $a-2\sqrt{bc}x$ from the diagonal. Divide all rows by $c$, which wouldn't change the determinant from being $0$. Call $r=\sqrt{b/c}$. The matrix is now Toeplitz with subdiagonal $r^2$, main diagonal $2rx$ and $1$ on the diagonal above.

Comment: Expand the determinant along the first row, to show that it satisfies the same [recurrence as the $U_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Recurrence_definition)

Comment: If $p_n(x)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of the $n \times n$ tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix, then with the [recurrence given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant) we have
$$
p_{n}(x) = (a-x)p_{n-1}(x) - bc p_{n-2}(x) \qquad n \geq 3.
$$

Comment: @Unknown Your title seems to imply that you're intent on specifically using induction. Is this the case, or are you open to other methods of proof?

Comment: yes. I am open to any proof.

Comment: One you have the recurrence, check the first two terms. By induction the whole sequence is those scaled and translated Chebyshev's polynomials. So, their roots are the same after the scaling and translation.